# Pubnub PHP message format for ios push notification

Tags: php, ios, angularjs, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

Per [PubNub PHP SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/api-reference) I publish a message as a JSON object on Pubnub to subscribed devices like this:

```
<?php
  $payload = array(
    "pn_apns"=>array(
      "aps"=>array(
        "alert"=>array(
          "title"=>"This is the Title",
          "body"=>"This is the actual message"
        ),
        "badge"=>1
      )),
    "message"=>"this is the embedded message",
    "data"=>array("my_key_1"=>"my_val_1")
  );


  $info = $pubnub->publish("my_channel_1", json_encode($payload);
  print_r($info);
```

The problem is the background Apple push notification alert on the actual device is not formatted properly with the title and the text message like this:

> **This is the Title**
>
> This is the actual message

...but instead is displayed as raw JSON text like this:

> {"pn_apns":{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"This is the Title","body":"This
> is the actual message"} ...

I am using the [Javascript SDK (AngularJS)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angularjs/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4) and [Phonegap push notification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) on the device.

How do I format the Apple push alert message properly in PHP?

Comment: Do **not** encode the JSON (`json_encode($payload)`). PubNub SDK will encode it for you. When you encode it, PubNub encodes it again and it comes out as encoded on the other end - where you could manually decode it but PubNub server will not process your APNS request as you desire. Let me know if that resolves it. This is mentioned in the PHP SDK docs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/api-reference#publish

Comment: @CraigConover  `$pubnub->publish("group","message")` requires a string for the message. Otherwise PHP throws an error. Plus, the message is properly decoded by PubNub's javascript SDK on the client when app in foreground.

Comment: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/api-reference#publish_args - JSON

Comment: Thanks-the error was NOT coming from pubnub PHP library. I got it working now.